# Bidirectional pipes in ubuntu / C++

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu

I have a network topology table stored in a textfile called (minlog.txt) that I piped into a python file which determines the nodes to be deleted and print them out.

Here's a screenshot of what I've done so far:

[image]

Now, I want to write a c++ code that:
- opens a pipe to the previous python program
- reads the output (stdout) of the python file

I thought about using fork to create a child process then inside of that I'll call pipe then exec (to read the stdout of python file).. but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the C++ launching the python, or is the python launching the C++, or what?

Comment: @cdarke the C++ is reading the output of the pyhton program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your C++ program is named "prog", the command line you want is:

```
cat minlog.txt | python graph.py | prog
```

Or, equivalently but more efficiently:

```
python graph.py < minlog.txt | prog
```

Comment: thanks for your response Rob. i'm not familair with c++ but would it be possible to open a pipe to the python program through my c++ program instead of the command line?

Comment: Yes. In order to do that, your C++ program would have to launch your Python program. Doing so would require the calls pipe(), dup() or dup2(), fork(), execv() or related exec*() call, and wait().

Comment: So in this case I don't need to use the command line pipe since it could be done in C++ instead. Also,

Comment: Yes, if you launch the Python program from inside the C++ program, then your command line would simply be `prog < minlog.txt`.